# Regex, any combination of select characters and case sensitive

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that matches any combination of the letters A,N,X and fullstop
It needs to be case sensitive too...

example of working values

```
A
X
ANX
AA.
AA.XX
AA.NN.XX
A.X.N
XXX.XXX.XXX
```

etc.

Exceptions:-

Full stops should only appear between sections of letters
Cannot start with a full stop

I've spent too long already trying to work this out and would appreciate a hand from a dab hand! Thanks :)

I'm using Javascript if that matters.

Comment: yes, any combination of those three characters with the full stop between or ending.

Comment: So `[AXN]{1,3}(?:\.[AXN]{1,3}){0,2}` ?

Comment: How the hell did you come up with that monstrosity, HamZa?

Comment: @JoeFrambach Think again, `[ANX.]+` would even match `.....`

Comment: Did you want it stopped at 3? Is ANXA acceptable?

Comment: It sounds to me that `.........` is valid.

Comment: @JoeFrambach *Sigh*, I overlooked `AA.` ...

Comment: So basically we could write: `[AXN][AXN.]*`

Comment: Not quite. That still matches `A............` which apparently is invalid.

Comment: @JoeFrambach I guessed too much today, it seems my guessing skills are decreasing :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^[ANX.]+$/
```

This should do the trick.

`^` matches the beginning of a string.

`[` to `]` matches *any* characters withing the brackets.

`+` repeats "one or more" of the previous group.

`$` matches the end of the string.

Edit: Since the question is super vague and not clear, here's one for `[ANX]` with dots between:

```
/([ANX]+\.?)*[ANX]+/
```

Comment: Fair point, have cleared up the full stop rule. Let me give this a bash, thanks Joe :)

Comment: var pattern = /([ANX]+\.?)*[ANX]+/;
pattern.test('XN.J');
returns true which shouldn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Add the `^` to the beginning and `$` at the end. I had that in the first regex but forgot it in the second.

Comment: Since you are so awesome at this I'm going to put up the full regex question as a separate query, if you fancy a challenge. Didn't really want to spend too much longer on this but you might enjoy it. It might also prove useful in the future for others.

Comment: Here's a nifty regex helper made by a stackoverflow user: http://www.debuggex.com/r/9xpX3f9CV1sz4G__/0

Answer (score 2):

#### In coffeescript

```
x=/^[ANX.]+$/
```

Reading as: A string containing only and at least one of the characters ANX.

---

```
"AN".match x
```

--> [ 'AN', index: 0, input: 'AN' ]

---

```
"ANx".match x
```

--> null

Hmmm was the exception there already at first? ;)

```
/^[ANX][ANX.]*$/
```

should do the trick then